# Определить имя класса, объекты которого занимают наибольший объём памяти JVM

Tags: java, профилирование, visualvm

Я в мониторинге и профилировании новичок и сейчас столкнулся с проблемой. Мне с помощью VisualVM необходимо определить имя класса, объекты которого занимают наибольший объём памяти JVM, а затем определить пользовательский класс, в экземплярах которого находятся эти объекты. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Для использования таких вещей как [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html) вовсе не обязательно быть мастером профилирования - достаточно просто понимать, как примерно JVM хранит объекты в памяти и как работает GC(последнее, к слову, тоже не обязательно).

Конкретный инструмент зависит о религиозных предпочтений - все они, конечно, чем-то отличаются друг от друга, но в целом выполняют одну и ту же задачу.